# Cassandra Error While running Debezium cassandra Connector

Tags: cassandra, debezium

I am facing below error while running debezium-cassandra connector: for CDC

```
sudo java -jar /home/centos/debezium-connector-cassandra-1.2.0.Beta2-jar-with-dependencies.jar /home/centos/debezium-connector-cassandra/deb_conf.properties
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Error instantiating snitch class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch'.
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:596)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:574)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createEndpointSnitch(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1045)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySnitch(DatabaseDescriptor.java:969)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.toolInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:192)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.toolInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:157)
    at io.debezium.connector.cassandra.CassandraConnectorContext.loadDdlFromDisk(CassandraConnectorContext.java:64)
    at io.debezium.connector.cassandra.CassandraConnectorContext.<init>(CassandraConnectorContext.java:36)
    at io.debezium.connector.cassandra.CassandraConnectorTask.run(CassandraConnectorTask.java:72)
    at io.debezium.connector.cassandra.CassandraConnectorTask.main(CassandraConnectorTask.java:61)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: DC or rack not found in snitch properties, check your configuration in: cassandra-rackdc.properties
    at org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.loadConfiguration(GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.java:76)
    at org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.<init>(GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:581)
    ... 9 more
```

I checked the `cassandra-rackdc.properties` is present in the `/etc/cassandra/`

`Cassandra Version:  Cassandra 3.11.6`
I have changes these param in `cassandra.yaml`

```
cdc_enabled: true
cdc_raw_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw
cdc_total_space_in_mb: 4096
cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms: 250
```

Edit: CASSANDRA_HOME defined and correct.

Comment: I got the same error when deploying with docker. Did you find a solution to it ?

Comment: after lot for back and forth, I found that this is in experimental phase and works only with local setup and not with org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch @Djuls